# Is it necessary to book two separate tickets if one passengers will deliberately miss the return flight?

Tags: tickets, emirates

My mother and sister are traveling from the UK to Dubai and booking a return ticket is cheaper than buying a one-way ticket. My mother will be returning but my sister will stay in Dubai and deliberately miss the return flight.

Would it cause my mother any problems if I do both tickets in one booking; the airline is Emirates?

Comment: Although it shouldn't, why not just book them separately so that it's a non-issue?

Comment: @Dorothy few reasons: costs slightly more, my mother has no credit card and can't choose seats

Comment: @pnuts in fact I have thought of this but my mother would never claim that my sister has died not she can provide a death certificate, so it's still a gamble to go with this theory

Comment: @pnuts in fact I'll be using a prepaid credit card for my sister so Emirates would never be able to penalise her, also I will do the check-in for her so my mother will enjoy two seats

Comment: @pnuts so even if I check-in online on the day of travel there is still a chance they would seat someone in my sisters seat?

Comment: What happens when your mom boards the flight, but her companion is a no show (since you checked them in together)?  How will your mom satisfy the flight crew / gate agents that your sister is not coming even though she checked in?  How well will your mom be able to lie about the true plan?  What happens if Emirates decides to deplane her because your sister mislead the airline with her ticket purchase and mom can't pay the penalty?  Is the potential hassle worth the cost savings?

Comment: @Ulkoma There is still a chance. If a passenger no-shows (which is not a matter of online check-in, but a matter of physically boarding the plane), their seat could be given away. It may be unlikely that this happens if the flight isn't full and there are other seats available to assign passengers, but it is a possibility. In short, you're buying air travel, not a seat, and the airline can reuse your seat if you don't show up. If you explicitly want two seats, you need to follow whatever the airline's special procedure is, if they have one, to purchase two seats for one person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact that the value of that return ticket is probably lost, no.
It will not affect other traveler's tickets that were bought together.